# How to Read Dump Files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dump, coredump

I am using procdump to get core dumps of a process or processes running and want to have a way to go through the data stored in those files in python.This is for both win/linux but with more of a linux focus.

Are there any existing Python libraries that I can use for this or are there suggestions of what can be used?

Comment: [https://pypi.org/project/yara-procdump-python/](https://pypi.org/project/yara-procdump-python/)